# Dotted Line between two word/sentences

Tags: css, html

I want a dotted line to fill the space between two words/sentences.
I need auto adjust dotted line between the words. 
But in fiddle result is not clear.

http://jsfiddle.net/shagun_jsfiddle/Z4DCH/6/

**HTML**

```
       <div style="position: relative; float: left;overflow: hidden; width: 1000px;" id="index1">
     <span class="left-side">Hello</span>
     <span class="right-side" >Dotted line</span>
</div>
<div style="position: relative; float: left;overflow: hidden; width: 850px; " id="index2">
     <span class="left-side">Hello</span>
     <span class="right-side" >Dotted line</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
        .left-side{width: auto;
     max-width: 26%;
     min-width: 0%;
     text-align: justify;
     background-color: transparent;
     display: inline-block;}
.left-side:before{float: right;
     width: 0;
     white-space: nowrap;
     line-height:11px;
     content: ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . " ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . " ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . " ;
}
.right-side{width: auto;
     max-width: 26%;
     min-width: 0%;
     background-color: transparent;
     float: right;
     display: inline-block;}
```

**In pic the circle content width is fixed with max and min width. So dots should be auto adjust. and should not overlap.**

[image]

Comment: I'm confused about what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: my repo is very low i can't send image

Comment: @Danield: I’ve added the fiddle.

Comment: @user2620387: are you saying that you want dots to fill the space between `<span class="left-side">` and `<span class="right-side">`, whatever the width of the parent `<div>` is?

Comment: now check my updated question

Comment: do you need to have a transparent background or can we use a color to cover overlapping issues?

Comment: @PuzzledBoy I haven't provided any solution yet. I just want to be clear on the requirements. Using a background color as KatieK did in her answer I believe is a valid method to make the dots 'end before the right span' if the page background is solid. **Edit:** Seems like PuzzledBoy deleted his comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is that your elements don't line up, it's because `#index1` has a different width than `#index2`.  Try making them the same width.

If your problem is that the dots don't reach to the "Dotted line" content, that's because `#index1` and `#index2` are wider than you have enough dots to cover.  Either make `#index1` and `#index2` skinnier, or add more dots.

If what you want is for the dots to fill in the all of the space between the left and right content (which may be dynamic), then try this:

HTML:

```
<div id="index1">
    <span class="left-side">Hello</span>
    <span class="right-side">Dotted line</span>
</div>

<div id="index2">
    <span class="left-side">Hello</span>
    <span class="right-side">Dotted line</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#index1, #index2 {
    width: 400px;
    background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAABCAIAAACDoBMqAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAadEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAFBhaW50Lk5FVCB2My41LjEwMPRyoQAAABJJREFUGFdj+I8EGBiQuP//AwBO2xfpJMYFgQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==) repeat-x bottom center;
}
#index2 {
    width: 250px;
}

.left-side {
    background: white;
}

.right-side {
    float: right;
    background: white;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Z4DCH/3/   (I've removed many of the unnecessary styles to simplify this example.)

This works by setting a repeating background image of 9x1 pixels, with one back pixel, as the background for the parent elements `#index1` and `#index2`.  Then, each of the child elements gets a white background to cover up that background image.

Comment: i want index1 and index2 different width

Comment: Please clarify what is the problem is, and what you expect to see.

Comment: My guess is he/she want dots to fill the space between `<span class="left-side">` and `<span class="right-side">`, whatever the width of the parent `<div>` is.

Comment: i want first santance and second sentance is fixed width like min-width:25%; and extra line goes to next line

Comment: @KatieK in your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Z4DCH/3/  dotted line with hello is not adjested clearly... should have start dotted line after the hello

Comment: @PaulD Waite you are right

Comment: @KatieK User need a dotted line ...... not a image.

Comment: I think @nishita sharma: want this -  http://jsfiddle.net/Z4DCH/7/

Comment: now check my updated question

Comment: So what was the problem with this answer? You can adjust the position of the dots by changing the background position property. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/Z4DCH/12/ the only downside is the use of background color to cover the overlapping